# Modify frame title afterwards

Tags: beamer

I want my frame title to look something like this:

`Exercise 1                                                             a)`

I know I could achieve this by doing the following:

```tex
\begin{frame}{Exercise 1\hfill a)}

\end{frame}
```

But I do not want to write `\hfill` all the time. Also, I can't use the subtitle for the `a)` as I want to use the subtitle for other stuff.

I thought something like this must be possible:

```tex
\begin{frame}{Exercise 1}
   \exnum{a)}
\end{frame}
```

```tex
\newcommand\exnum[1]{\frametitle{\insertframetitle\hfill{#1}}}
```

But I cannot use `\insertframetitle` there, and I don't know why.

Does anybody have an idea how to achieve what I want?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It will be easier for others to help you if you add a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/201628), that is, a minimal yet compilable code that shows the problem. For example, in this case to propose a useful solution it might be important to know what beamer style you are using.

Comment: Why not `\newcommand\exnum[1]{\frametitle{Exercise\hfill{#1}}}`?

Comment: @Werner 'cause I want to hard-code the word exercise. I might give different frames different titles.

Comment: @Luke: Then you could use a macro for that: `\newcommand{\frametype}{Exercise}` and use `\newcommand{\exnum}[1]{\frametitle{\frametype\hfill #1}}`... and then change `\renewcommand{\frametype}{Example}`, say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar approach as @Werner's comment, but instead of hardcoding anything, you could create a macro with two arguments:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newcommand{\mytitle}[2]{\frametitle{#1\hfill#2}}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
    \mytitle{Exercise}{a)}
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's a great idea. I was kinda stuck thinking that I have to set the title when starting the frame env. I somehow forgot that It's just fine to do it inside the frame env.

Comment: @Luke Personally I actually prefer to set the title inside the frame. The `\frametitle` macros is much more powerful and robust than the hacky `\begin{frame}{title}` syntax.

Comment: Why is `\begin{frame}{title} hacky? I did not know this?`

Comment: @Luke The code inside beamer to get this working is quite hacky. Life would be so much easier without this syntax :)

Comment: ah thanks for explaining. The I'll probably stop using this syntax :)

Comment: @Luke :thumbsup: